# ontableave/onleave not working for <rich:tab>

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to call javascript action in JSF rich:tab on tag ontableave/onleave. But these tags never seem to be working on moving out of the tab. How can I solve it?

In the below example onheaderdblclick executes but not ontableave.

```
<rich:tab name="#{messages['person info']}" 
    onheaderdblclick="javascript:alert('hi headerdoubleclick')" 
    id="tabPersonalInformation" value="PERSON_INFO"   
    ontableave="javascript:alert('hi tableave')">
```

Comment: Where's the example?

Comment: <rich:tab name="#messages['personInfo']}" onheaderdblclick="javascript:alert('hi headerdoubleclick')"
id="tabPersonalInformation" value="PERSON_INFO" ontableave="javascript:alert()" onleave="javascript:alert('onleave')">

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was solved, i was probably using 2 tags ontableave and onleave at the same time. onleave tag was triggered after the change.